# How to hide element outside of IFRAME when user touches/swipes any part of the IFRAME on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, iframe, touch-event

I need help in fixing/optimizing my code when I try to hide a DIV that is outside of the IFRAME when swiping on the IFRAME on a mobile device via touchmove event. The IFRAME content is within the same domain name as this code but is on a different directory.

Example HTML structure:

```
<iframe id="iframe_to_swipe" src="SAME ORIGIN" />
<div id="div_to_hide"></div>

<style>
#div_to_hide {display: block}
</style>

window.onload = function() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("iframe_to_swipe");
    oFrame.contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("div_to_hide").style.display = "none";
    };
};
```

I have the code above which perfectly works on a desktop via onClick event. And below is what I've tried for mobile but NOT working.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("iframe_to_swipe").addEventListener("touchmove", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("div_to_hide").style.display = "none";
}
```

I want to hide "div_to_hide" when I swipe/touch "iframe_to_swipe" on mobile device

Comment: That's because the `touchmove` event happens on the content of the iframe and not the iframe itself. If the content of that iframe is from a different origin (other website), then there's not much you can do about it. The [Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from doing anything with it. I would try looking at the `focus` event instead. I haven't tested it, but to me it would make sense that it would work.

Comment: @icecub Thank you for reminding me to mention that the iframe content is within the same origin (same domain name). I've edited the information above.

Comment: In that case it's pretty easy. Just create the `touchmove` event in the script inside your iframe and use [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) to hide the element outside of it.

Comment: @icecub Sorry, I'm a bit noob at JS. Can you provide an example/modification based on my code above? Really much appreciated.

Comment: It's easy. Edit the code of the iframe content. Create the `touchmove` event handler there. Something like `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){ parent.getElementById("div_to_hide").style.display = "none"; }); });`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `window.parent.getElementById("div_to_hide").style.display = "none";` inside that code instead of just `parent`.

Comment: You might also have to use `parent.document.getElementById..`. I forgot that `parent` refers to the parent `window` element, not the `document`.

Comment: @icecub I placed this code on the iframe content and it doesn't seem to work. `<script> window.onload = function() { document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){ parent.document.getElementById("div_to_hide").style.display = "none"; }); }); }; </script>`

Comment: Sorry, I went to bed at that time. No that wouldn't work because `window.onload = function() {` and `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` both do the opposite of eachother. The first tries to load the code _before_ the html is loaded in and the second tries to load it _after_ it's loaded in. You shouldn't add more code to what I've told you, except for the `<script>` elements.